# Remote debugging with the perl plugin in intellij via jetbrains client on ssh

Tags: perl, intellij-idea, ssh, remote-debugging

I have code base that I work on that I have to ssh into a server to access. I usually do this through vscode, but I have been wanting to try out intellij for remote debugging. Basically, I enter a script on the command line, and it starts up a sandbox of our website that runs on the server. I want to connect my debugger to the process running on the server to help things out. Use the perl debugger plugin, there are some values you have to enter to configure this:

```
export PERL5_DEBUG_ROLE=server
export PERL5_DEBUG_HOST=<ip_address_of_your_machine>
export PERL5_DEBUG_PORT=<port_on_which_your_IDE_is_listening>
```

Then after than, you should be able you run
perl -d:Camelcadedb <your_script>
and it should work. The problem is, I have tried every value for these and I just cannot get it to work. Can anyone tell me, it good detail, how to do this, preferably with an example of them they did remote debugging perl through the perl intellij plugin? Or is there any better way anyone *knows for sure* will work that you could suggest? Thanks.